# Debugging potentially orphaned sockets in a C# Tcp Server

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, sockets, tcp

I'm not supplying my specific code because it would just be too much.  At any rate I suspect I have a problem with sockets getting orphaned in a custom Tcp asynchronous server built with C#.  It targets framework 4, and is a production service (the problem only appears in production).  I have two questions regarding general debugging of sockets.

1. How can I determine if I have orphaned sockets?  Some perfmon counter or similar?
2. Is it not true that TcpClient.Close() closes all underlying streams immediately?  I've seen conflicting accounts, so I am concerned that since the service does not explicitly close underlying streams this might be a source of the problem (if indeed orphaned sockets are the problem).

Comment: What does it even mean?  Sockets have parents?

Comment: I suppose I could have phrased that better, but it's quite clear I'm referring to the potential existence of sockets that were never completely disposed of, particularly in the context of, as I mentioned TcpClient objects which contain methods for getting a NetworkStream.  Said stream is just a high level wrapper for a raw socket.  But thank you for the constructive condescension.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/socket_sniffer.html for monitoring open sockets on your machine.
2. Check the value of the `LingerState` property on your `TcpClient`. Also, the .NET `TcpClient.Close()` method call eventually results in a call to WINAPI `shutdown()` function in **ws2_32.dll**, so if you are debugging you can link against the debug libraries and put a breakpoint etc. whenever `shutdown()` gets called.